# How to display a contact number in android

Tags: android

I need to display a Contact Number in android.So far I done it in `textView`.But I couldn't able to get the result.

**For Eg**: If Contact Number is 86081***20.

I need to display this number in `android.xml`.Anybody can help me with these.Thank you.

**contact.xml**

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView9"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/number1" />
```

**strings.xml:**

```
<string name="number1">86081***20 </string>
```

I done it like these.

Finally output shows like `@String/number1`

Comment: *I couldn't able to get the desired result.* means? Please clarify. Show code and snapshot of desired result and current output

Comment: did not get you on "I need to display this number in android-xml" pl explain this too

Comment: @MysticMagic  `<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView9"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/number1"
        />` I done it like these.Finally output shows like `@String/number1`.But I didnt get the number

Comment: define @String/number1 in string.xml

Comment: yes I defined it like these:  `<string name="number1">86081***20 </string>` @AmanSingh

Comment: post your java code then.

Comment: pls post ur string.xml

Comment: Recheck name of string resource. This should work. Post your xml code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android:text="@string/number1"
```

will only work when you have any string resource with that name in your `values/strings.xml` file.

```
<string name="number1">86081***20</string>
```

But mostly you are getting it dynamically, so you will need to set the textview text in java like this in `onCreate`:

```
String someContactNum = "86081***20";
TextView txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contact_text);
txtView.setText(someContactNum);
```

Hope it helps.